# Start external Activity as a separate task

Tags: android, flutter, android-activity

I have a Flutter app with Single Activity with `launchMode` as `singleTask`. I have integrated Google tap&pay SDK into my app which launches(`startActivityForResult`) a separate `Activity` on click of a button. As per the requirement I have to define an `intent-filter` to verify a token in my app. It looks something like this:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="com.example.action.ACTIVATE_TOKEN"/>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

The above `intent-filter` is part of the Single Activity of my Flutter app. Now the `Activity` from the SDK have an action that will call my app(`startActivityForResult`) again with the above `action` and I have to send back the result after verification to the SDK's `Activity`. Since my app `Activity` is launched in `singleTask` the `Activity` launched by the SDK is killed and is not waiting for the result to be returned.

The flow looks something like this:
`A` is my app's Activity. `B` is the SDK's Activity.

```
A--->B--->A--->B

or

A---startActivityForResult--->B---startActivityForResult--->A---setResult--->B
```

How can I make sure that the `Activity` launched by the SDK is still active after my `Activity` is launched again through an `intent-filter`?

Comment: I think, you need to change the launch mode of your activity to singleInstance. In singleInstance launch mode, only one instance of the activity is allowed to exist in the system, regardless of the task. So when you start the SDK's activity from your activity, and then start your activity again through the intent-filter, the SDK's activity will still be alive and waiting for the result to be returned.

Comment: Tried didn't work! Since the new activity is launched using startActivityForResult. Both are placed in the same task. This behavior was implemented in 5.0 and above.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the singleTask launch mode from your Flutter app's

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:launchMode="standard">  
</activity>
```

Comment: Yeah I used singleTop which worked but that creates two instances of my flutter activity.

Comment: try using 
<activity
    android:name=".YourSingleTaskActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">
</activity>

<activity
    android:name=".YourSingleInstanceActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance">
</activity>